# How to remove command line from a compiled program?

Tags: winapi, user-interface, command-line, codeblocks

I have recently started a tutorial to learn how to code GUI using Windows API and I have come upon an unexpected question which I think is kind of silly. I am using Code::Blocks with OpenWatcom compiler as default and I have created a simple GUI program compiling and linking well. The problem is when I try to launch the program, even from the release version something like the command line shows up behind the window of my program, like I tried to run it through the compile & run option of the Code::Blocks. Is there any way to remove the command line from showing up?[image: This is how it looks like when I run it.]

EDIT: It is not a problem with my main definition. This is my main definition: |

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, the PE executable format has a flag that indicates whether the executable mode is "console mode" or "GUI mode". If "console mode", then the OS will attach a console window (opening a new one if necessary) whenever the program is run.

There will be a linker setting somewhere in your build environment that controls whether the EXE you generate is marked as console or GUI.

Comment: Hegwill I found that option and although I changed the project option so that the release file is GUI application and not Console application the only difference is that now when I run the program through the build enviroment the "command line" closes right after I close the window when before that the command line just waited for a  keystroke to close...Still the release executable has the same result :/

Comment: Ok, if you have the `dumpbin.exe` utility (or equivalent), check to make sure the executable is marked the way you want it to be.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Windows available right now. Another thing to try would be to create a *new* project that starts out in the correct GUI mode, and see whether that behaves properly.

Comment: Okay, try another IDE. I know that [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) will definitely do it (and it's free). That also contains `dumpbin.exe` so you can find out whether your current toolchain is broken or not.

Comment: I found the solution. If you do create a new project and you immediately change it to GUI Application before linking the first time it does show the command line however if you choose to create a Win32 GUI application before you actually create the project then the command line doesnt show up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe you can set int nCmdShow to a value that is something like false?

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the [/SUBSYSTEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) linker option. It is currently set to `CONSOLE` and you need to change it to `WINDOWS`. The documentation mandates how the `main` needs to be changed:

> Application does not require a console, probably because it creates
>   its own windows for interaction with the user. If **WinMain** or **wWinMain**
>   is defined for native code, or **WinMain(HISTANCE *, HINSTANCE *, char
>   *, int)** or **wWinMain(HINSTANCE *, HINSTANCE *, wchar_t *, int)** is defined for managed code, WINDOWS is the default.

Specifically for `Code::Blocks`, the linker option can be changed by [this process](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.DisablingConsoleWindow):

> In Code::Blocks simply open the Project->Properties dialog, switch to
>   the "Build Targets" tab and change the "Type" of the build targets you
>   want to modify to "GUI Application" or "Console Application". No need
>   to worry about the "main" function.

Comment: As I have stated above to the comment made by Greg Hegwill I have already done that, rebuild the project but still the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `main` function, you need to use Win32's standard entry point `WinMain`:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow);
```

See: http://sol.gfxile.net/wintut/ch2.html

Or, if you can't recompile, in Windows 7 you can just do:

`START myProgram` {enter}

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126410

Comment: Already done that. That's not the case. Maybe the main file shouldn't be named main.cpp also or am I wrong?