# Creating an "invisible" windows program in C/C++

Tags: c, winapi, background, silent

Ok this is a continuation from this question: [How to make a simple Hello World "invisible" in Windows (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488487/how-to-make-a-simple-hello-world-invisible-in-windows-c-c)

People gave me some guidance and here I am with a new qestion:

Aight after doing some research I am stuck again. People on the internet claim that by just creating a win32 application there will be no graphical indications.

Here is the code that does this (I'm pretty sure you already know this but w/e)

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

//code
return 0;
}
```

So the code typed inside main is not displayed. I don't really get what kind of code they mean but for example:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    while (1) {
    }
}
```

This program pops a Cmd window just fine.

I've also found that by initializing values at the STARTUPINFO structure like that

```
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
memset(&StartupInfo, 0, sizeof(StartupInfo));
// set the size of the structure
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
// tell the application that we are setting the window display 
// information within this structure
StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
// set the window display to HIDE
StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
```

would hide the console window. This doesn't work either for me though. I have this feeling that I am missing a major concept here so I need your knowledge guys. I want to create simple .exe with something like a while loop or a simple print that doesn't display a thing. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove command line from a compiled program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203539/how-to-remove-command-line-from-a-compiled-program) Short answer: create an executable with "subsystem GUI" instead of "subsystem Console" (see your linker options).

Comment: Hmm I didn't spot that unfortunately, I will check it out though. Thanks for the input as well man

Comment: No worries, I only knew about that duplicate because I answered that other question. :)

Comment: So i checked the other question and it is indeed very relevant. I found this link there: http://www.irrlicht3d.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.DisablingConsoleWindow . It pretty much sums up all I was asking :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a specific compiler option to do this; it's not a property of the code itself. I will assume you are using Visual Studio to compile.

Go to `Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem` and set it to `Windows`. If you do this and run your program and, for example, put your program into an infinite loop, you'll have to kill it from the Task Manager.

<strike>I have no idea how to do this on GCC.</strike> Gerald has told me in the comments that using `--subsystem,windows` or `-mwindows` will do this for GCC. Note that `-mwindows` links the GDI libraries as well.

Comment: --subsystem,windows or -mwindows for GCC. -mwindows also adds the GDI libraries to the linker

Comment: Alright i will check it out right now. I use Code::Blocks but I have Visual studio aswell just not familiar with it.